# JQuery slideUp/slideDown doesn't work as supposed to

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slidetoggle

I am struggling to make a div which will disappear after the slideUp() action.

html:

```
<div class="rounded gradient" id="BCBox">
    <ul class="BCSelect">
        <li style="text-align:left;">Welcome <b>Username</b>,<br/><br/>Bla Bla Bla: </li>
        <li>
        <div class="button2 BCButton">
        </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
​
```

javascript:

```
$('#BCBox').height($('#BCBox').height());
$('#BCBox').slideUp();​
```

You can see a demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/4feU9/7/

Somehow the box doesn't want to animate the way it is supposed to... It slides up very fast. can you help? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There is no js in the fiddle? also please don't just post a link post some code and your actual errors

Comment: There is no jQuery or Javascript in that fiddle. In jQuery for height animation to work properly the element must have a set height (which you can set from jquery using $('#element').height($('#element').height());

Comment: Now there is JS, sorry, I must have mixed something up with the versions: http://jsfiddle.net/4feU9/5/

Comment: @gillesc I added the line you have proposed, but it still doesn't work properly: http://jsfiddle.net/4feU9/7/

Comment: What is `$('#BCBox').height($('#BCBox').height());` suppose to do?

Comment: @jleagle it suppose to set the height if it is not set yet. slide animation in jQuery used to fail if the height wasn't specify (not sure how actual it is with the current version of jQuery tho)

Comment: @tromax put all in a $(function() { }); so it is called on page load. Now it animate but I think some of your CSS conflict with it, as it is sliding it up but the wrapper element doesn't hide it so you still see it until the end of the animation.

Comment: @gillesc I am aware of that, and that is the nauture of my question. Which css property I should change to have it working properly?

Comment: @gillesc: Wrong, jsfiddle puts it in the onload automatically (see the left menu)

Comment: @rlemon Posting links to a jsfiddle is far better then copy pasting the code.

Comment: @DavidMulder no, StackOverflow is a resource community. Posting to a third party site makes future readers rely on ***that*** site to see the issue at hand. what is jsfiddle goes bye bye in a year. this question will be useless. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115056/should-i-edit-posts-to-pull-in-the-code-from-jsfiddle

Comment: @rlemon, you realize that the edit you made made the question worse rather than better as forgot to include the relevant part of the code which caused the problem (thus distracting future visitors from the actual problem). Secondly if he would have copied *all* the code from the jsfiddle (which is the only alternative for less exp users) you would have probably been the first to complain that he should narrow down the code (which you failed to correctly yourself). And lastly, the (dis)use of jsfiddle is a huge debate on meta, so quoting a single partly irrelevant question is short sighted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are floating it to the right with a big margin top (the margin is part of the element and thus also animated during the slideup). Here you can see that absolutely positioning the element for example fixes the animation: http://jsfiddle.net/4feU9/8/

html

```
<div class="rounded gradient" id="BCBox" >

        <ul class="BCSelect">
            <li style="text-align:left;">Welcome <b>Username</b>,<br/><br/>Bla Bla Bla:
            </li>
            <li >
                <div class="button2 BCButton"></div>    
            </li>
        </ul>

    </div>​
```

javascript

```
$('#BCBox').slideUp();
```

​

Comment: Yeah, but how can I position it properly next to some other element now, with this having an absolute position?

Comment: as long as the container is `position: relative;`, absolute positioned items will be *relative* to the container and not the page.

Comment: And either way, the absolute positioning was just a quick example, you can even have an element with margins containing this element without margins which also solves the problem.